# How can I change the effect of those buttons to the select so I can delete the buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, select, translation

I want to use the select instead of the buttons to translate this page, the buttons i want to delete. the button are working perfectly the only problem is thaqt they shouldn't be there, instead there should be only the select.

```js
var arrLang = {
  'en': {
    'home': 'Home',
    'about': 'About Us',
    'contact': 'Contact Us',
    'desc': 'This is my description'
  },
  'km': {
    'home': 'ទំព័រដើម',
    'about': 'អំពីយើង',
    'contact': 'ទំនាក់ទំនងយើងខ្ញុំ',
    'desc': 'នេះគឺជាអត្ថបទរបស់ខ្ញុំ'
  }
};

// Process translation
$(function() {
  $('.translate').click(function() {
    var lang = $(this).attr('id');

    $('.lang').each(function(index, item) {
      $(this).text(arrLang[lang][$(this).attr('id')]);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="en" class="translate">English</button>
<button id="km" class="translate">ខ្មែរ</button>
<select id="language" class="translate" style="">
  <option value="en">English</option>
  <option value="km">ខ្មែរ</option>
</select>

<ul>
  <li class="lang" id="home">Home</li>
  <li class="lang" id="about">About Us</li>
  <li class="lang" id="contact">Contact Us</li>
</ul>
<p class="lang" id="desc">This is my description</p>

<br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things here:

1. Delete the buttons
2. Change the event listener to `onchange` since that will fire when the select value changes.
3. Get the `.val()` instead of the `id` of the select (which holds your lang key)

Here's an example with those changes:

```js
var arrLang = {
  'en': {
    'home': 'Home',
    'about': 'About Us',
    'contact': 'Contact Us',
    'desc': 'This is my description'
  },
  'km': {
    'home': 'ទំព័រដើម',
    'about': 'អំពីយើង',
    'contact': 'ទំនាក់ទំនងយើងខ្ញុំ',
    'desc': 'នេះគឺជាអត្ថបទរបស់ខ្ញុំ'
  }
};

// Process translation
$(function() {
  $('.translate').on("change", function() {
    var lang = $(this).val();

    $('.lang').each(function(index, item) {
      $(this).text(arrLang[lang][$(this).attr('id')]);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="language" class="translate" style="">
  <option value="en">English</option>
  <option value="km">ខ្មែរ</option>
</select>

<ul>
  <li class="lang" id="home">Home</li>
  <li class="lang" id="about">About Us</li>
  <li class="lang" id="contact">Contact Us</li>
</ul>
<p class="lang" id="desc">This is my description</p>

<br>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your function you use the ID of the buttons to select the language. If u want to change that to a select field you can use the value of the select options instead. Here are both ways for comparison:

```js
var arrLang = {
  'en': {
    'home': 'Home',
    'about': 'About Us',
    'contact': 'Contact Us',
    'desc': 'This is my description'
  },
  'km': {
    'home': 'ទំព័រដើម',
    'about': 'អំពីយើង',
    'contact': 'ទំនាក់ទំនងយើងខ្ញុំ',
    'desc': 'នេះគឺជាអត្ថបទរបស់ខ្ញុំ'
  }
};

// Process translation
$(function() {
  $('button.translate').click(function() {
    var lang = $(this).attr('id');

    $('.lang').each(function(index, item) {
      $(this).text(arrLang[lang][$(this).attr('id')]);
    });
  });
});
$(function() {
  $('select.translate').on('change', function () {
     var lang = $(this).val();
     
     $('.lang').each(function(index, item) {
        $(this).text(arrLang[lang][$(this).attr('id')]);
      });
   })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<button id="en" class="translate">English</button>
<button id="km" class="translate">ខ្មែរ</button>
<select id="language" class="translate" style="">
    <option value="en">English</option>
    <option value="km">ខ្មែរ</option>
</select>

<ul>
  <li class="lang" id="home">Home</li>
  <li class="lang" id="about">About Us</li>
  <li class="lang" id="contact">Contact Us</li>
</ul>
<p class="lang" id="desc">This is my description</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are required to use `.change()` for select for proper functioning.
I have made sufficient changes to your code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Multiple Languages with Jquery and Json</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var arrLang = {
      'en': {
        'home': 'Home',
        'about': 'About Us',
        'contact': 'Contact Us',
        'desc': 'This is my description'
      },
      'km': {
        'home': 'ទំព័រដើម',
        'about': 'អំពីយើង',
        'contact': 'ទំនាក់ទំនងយើងខ្ញុំ',
        'desc': 'នេះគឺជាអត្ថបទរបស់ខ្ញុំ'
      }
    };
    
    // Process translation
    $(document).ready(()=>{
      $("#language").change(function(){
        var lang = $(this).val()
        $('.lang').each(function(index, item){
          $(this).text(arrLang[lang][$(this).attr('id')])
        });
      })
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <select id="language" class="translate" style="">
      <option value="en">English</option>
      <option value="km">ខ្មែរ</option>
  </select>

  <ul>
    <li class="lang" id="home">Home</li>
    <li class="lang" id="about">About Us</li>
    <li class="lang" id="contact">Contact Us</li>
  </ul>
  <p class="lang" id="desc">This is my description</p>

  <br>
</body>
</html>
```